# Php function to remove spaces from uploaded photo

Tags: php, function, upload

I am using Jquery uploader to upload images to my website. It uses a file called uploadhandler.php to manipulate the files. Inside the uploadhandler.php is the following function which appears to make changes to how the filename is formatted etc.
The problem I am having is if I upload a file with spaces in the file name it doesn't appear to be removing the spaces in the file name. Does anyone know how I can edit it to add an extra command to remove any spaces in the file name, or point me in the right direction on how to do it ?.

```
 protected function trim_file_name($name, $type, $index, $content_range) {

    // Remove path information and dots around the filename, to prevent uploading

    // into different directories or replacing hidden system files.

    // Also remove control characters and spaces (\x00..\x20) around the filename:

    $file_name = trim(basename(stripslashes($name)), ".\x00..\x20");

    // Add missing file extension for known image types:

    if (strpos($file_name, '.') === false &&

        preg_match('/^image\/(gif|jpe?g|png)/', $type, $matches)) {

        $file_name .= '.'.$matches[1];

    }

    while(is_dir($this->get_upload_path($file_name))) {

        $file_name = $this->upcount_name($file_name);

    }

    $uploaded_bytes = $this->fix_integer_overflow(intval($content_range[1]));

    while(is_file($this->get_upload_path($file_name))) {

        if ($uploaded_bytes === $this->get_file_size(

                $this->get_upload_path($file_name))) {

            break;

        }

        $file_name = $this->upcount_name($file_name);

    }

    return $file_name;

}
```

Comment: You may try and go for the one-line `preg_replace( '/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', ... )`

Comment: or a `str_replace(' ', '', $file_name)`

Comment: well a space is a legit file name character.

Comment: From memory older versions of IE have problems with spaces in filenames. Should be all good if they're simply url_encoded though.

Comment: exactly, and you should of course use url_encode anyway so don't 'fix' what's not 'broke'

Comment: The reason I want to remove them is because the image preview uses a shadowbox type popup, and when the files have spaces in the name it comes up with image not found :-)

Comment: then your not using urlencode(), which you should be regardless of space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line:

```
$file_name = trim(basename(stripslashes($name)), ".\x00..\x20");
```

Will remove spaces "around" the filename, such as "foo " because of the `x20` bit which is a space.  You could simply add directly after this line:

```
$file_name = str_replace(" ", "", $file_name);
```

Easy as that!  Also remember, when you use the 2nd parameter in `trim()` you remove the "default" list of characters listed in the manual ( http://php.net/trim ) and replace it with your own ...

I would also point out, I would **never** use the filename as given by the browser in `$_FILES[$x]['name']` ... It simply opens too many questions and possibilities up.  One technique to avoid the issue altogether might be to simply use the `md5()` or `sha1()` or similar of the file's *contents*, example:

```
$file_name = md5_file($_FILES['your_file_tag_name']['tmp_name']);
```

That way in theory, you never ever have spaces in the files, or "dirty" filenames ... And in addition, if a user uploads two files with the precise same contents, you simply need to check for the file's existance, and if it already exists, you already have *that exact same file*.  Hope this helps, this all assumes you're doing file uploads, which I'm not 100% certain you are.